# Form Builder Customer validation in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I  have created a registration form in angular2 using `<form>` as shown below:

```
<form [formGroup]="RegisterForm3">

                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label>Last Date:</ion-label>
                        <ion-input formControlName="LastDate" min="2016" type="date"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
                    <hr/>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label>Next  Date:</ion-label>
                        <!--<ion-input formControlName="NextPayDate" type="number"></ion-input>-->
                        <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" formControlName="NextDate" (OnChanges)="npay()"></ion-datetime>
                    </ion-item>
                    <span style="color:red" *ngIf="!RegisterForm3.controls.NextPayDate.valid &&  (!RegisterForm3.controls.NextDate.dirty || submitAttempt)"> * Next day Must Be Greater Than Today's Date </span>
                    <hr/>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label>SecondDate:</ion-label>
                        <!--<ion-input formControlName="SecondDate" type="number"></ion-input>-->
                        <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" formControlName="SecondDate"></ion-datetime>
                    </ion-item>
                    <hr/>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label>Original Date:</ion-label>

                        <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" formControlName="RequestedDate"></ion-datetime>
                    </ion-item>
                    <span style="color:red" *ngIf="!RegisterForm3.controls.RequestedDate.valid &&  (!RegisterForm3.controls.RequestedDate.dirty || submitAttempt)"> * RequestedDate Should Be 5 days Greater Than Today's Date </span>
                </form>
```

Then form.ts

```
  this.RegisterForm3 = formBuilder.group({           
        LastDate: ['', Validators.required],
        NextDate:['',NextDayValidator.isValid],
        SecondDate: ['',Validators.required],
        RequestedDate:['',OriginalDateValidator.isValid],

    });
```

Then I have created two custom validators class.

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class OriginalDateValidator {

    static isValid(control: FormControl): any {
        var todaydate =new Date(Date.now() + (1000  * 60  * 60  * 24 * 10))
        console.log(todaydate);
        let duedate=new Date(control.value);
        console.log(duedate);
        console.log(duedate<todaydate);
       //alert(npay);
        if(!duedate){
           return {
                "is empty": true
            };
        }
        if(duedate<todaydate){

             return {
                "Day must 5day greater then todaydate": true
            };
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

For now the problem is, RequestedDate must be a NextDate or SecondDate. So, I need to test this condition in my OriginalDateValidators class. Only me being able to access the RequestedDate, controls value alone in my  validators. But I need to access NextDate and SecondDate also, in my validators. Is it possible to access those fields in my validator's class? Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to get access to other controls via reference to formGroup:

```
export class OriginalDateValidator {
  static isValid(control: FormControl): any {
    let formGroup = control.parent;
    if(formGroup) {
      let secondDateControl = formGroup.get('SecondDate');
      console.log(secondDateControl.value);
    }
```

Comment: hi @YurZui its possible to get error message from validators class